# Using PTRACE_POKEDATA to replace data in the heap of a process

Tags: c, linux, memory, heap-memory, ptrace

I would like to use ptrace in order to attach my tool to a Linux process, read and write to the heap memory of this process and again detach my tool. 
Actually, it's not working although there is no error. I can not see any modifications in the heap memory of the process after I run the tool. Anyway, I'm quite not sure if that is possible in general. Currently, my C code looks like this:

```
      int res = 0, i = 0;
      int size = heap_address->end - heap_address->start;

      char tmp_page[size];
      memset(tmp_page, 'x', size); // just a test, I know this makes no sense

      printf(" -> Attaching to process...\n");
      res = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
      if (res == -1) printf(" -> Error: ptrace attach\n");
      res = waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);
      if (res != pid) printf(" -> Error: waitpid\n");

      printf(" -> Replacing heap\n");
      for (i=0; i < size; i+=4) {
       res = ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, heap_address->start+i, *(int *)(tmp_page+i));
         if (res == -1) printf(" -> Error: ptrace pokedata\n");
      }

      printf(" -> Detaching from process...\n");
      res = ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
      if (res == -1) printf(" -> Error: ptrace detach\n");
```

Comment: There is nothing *obviously* wrong with the code shown (and yes, this sort of thing is supposed to work) so here are some debugging suggestions: (1) Change all your error printfs to be of the form `printf("[what you have now]: %s\n", strerror(errno))`. (For this to work you must `#include <string.h>` and `<errno.h>`.)  (2) If `heap_address` is set incorrectly, you may be writing to the wrong memory area.  How are you setting it?  (3) How are you looking for "modifications in the heap memory of the process"? Note that only one process at a time can be `PTRACE_ATTACH`-ed to any given process.

Comment: Don't forget tu run your executable with root privileges. Anyway you can try my code out https://github.com/petrbel/pvu2/tree/master/gdb

but watch out for sleeper's `foo` address