# Replace Hex code of shared object library loaded in memory

Tags: c++, memory, replace, hex, .so

How can I find and replace hex code of .so files that are loaded in memory at runtime using C or C++?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099916/using-ptrace-pokedata-to-replace-data-in-the-heap-of-a-process

Comment: I should add this all terribly depends on the OS so you need to provide more info in such a question. There might be a cleaner way to achieve what you want. The memory of your own code is likely to be in read only paged memory, not directly accessible and you will need to request the OS for access to it. Hence PTRACE_ATTACH/POKEDATA.

Comment: Okay, the OS is android x86 with root access. i know the offsets and i know the hex code in the .so files i wish to replace once they are loaded to memory

Comment: Seems that the ptrace approach I mentioned above would work on android - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433451/linux-ptrace-read-whole-memory-page however to get the address to start with you can use https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-dl_iterate_phdr/

Comment: There is too much to paste out of this guys approach but he covers everything needed - I 'm sure you can adapt this to C - https://ancat.github.io/python/2019/01/01/python-ptrace.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I will look into it.